# Reference VC ++ WinRT project in C# WinRT project

Tags: c#, c++, windows-runtime

I need to reference a VC++ WinRT project in a C# WinRT project with the following configuration.

- JS Project

  - C# WinRT Project

    - VC++ WinRT Project

      - C++ library

I need the VC++ WinRT Project to communicate with the C++ library, the C# WinRT project was created while debugging the error, it isn't necessary.

## Problem

---

The C# WinRT Project can't find the `.dll` from the VC++ WinRT Project, because the only referened file is the `.winmd` file which don't contain any implementations. The following error is thrown when initializing the public class from the VC++ project on some PCs (It somehow works on some):

```
"Error : The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"
```

---

All projects are referenced in the order shown above and also have been added as a Solution dependency.

I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Which Visual Studio version are you using? I tried top down: Universal C# RT Unit Test --> Universal RT C# class lib --> Universal RT C++ class lib but could not reproduce your error. I've tested it in VS 2015

Comment: @HenryRoeland I am using Visual Studio 2017